# How to transition label text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, transition

I'm trying to transition chart labels and have managed to transition to a new position and change the fill but I can't get it to update with the new items data.  Is this possible?

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/sz2Lo5rm/)

```
var margin = { top: 50, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100 },
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    Items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5",
             "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8",    "Item 9", "Item 10"],

svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var Labels = svg.selectAll(".dLabel")
    .data(Items); // select the data points and set their data

gEnter = Labels.enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d; })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 40; })
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

Labels.exit().remove();

Items = ["Item 9", "Item 10", "Item 8", "Item 7", "Item 6",
         "Item 5", "Item 4", "Item 3", "Item 2", "Item 1"];

Labels.transition().duration(1500).ease("exp-in-out")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + 50 + "," + 0 + ")"; });
```

Comment: Your pattern is not right here. You need to create a function that updates the .data() attribute of your group to the new Items dataset. When that happens, the update and transition will occur. See this faq: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Comment: In line with what the previous commenter suggested.... http://jsfiddle.net/sz2Lo5rm/2/

Comment: Very nice solution thank you.    Works great with chrome but I can't get it to update properly with IE10?

Comment: Must have been a delay on the server.  Working as expected now.  Thanks again.  Steve